# Visual Basic - ListIndex problems

Tags: arrays, vb.net, listview

So here's my problem: I'm creating a 'jukebox' using two listviews, you double-click one, and it adds info to another listview.  Additionally, it adds the relevant mp3 info into an array.  This array will be used by Windows Media Player to play songs back-to-back.

Somehow I'm successful in transferring over the correct info into the 2nd listview (lvTrackList), but after I double-click a second or third row of info, the same information from the first double-click goes back through the If statement.  My array begins spacing out the tracks (for example, after adding three songs, the array says that the first two spots are 0, and the third slot is the first song that was selected) ... Please help!!!

```
        Dim songsArray() As String = {"FurryLewis-BillyLyonsAndStackolee.Mp3", "GusCannon-PoorBoyALongWayFromHome.Mp3", "JoeMcCoy-PileDriverBlues.Mp3", "LouisArmstrong-ComeBack,SweetPapa.mp3"}
        Dim queueArray() As String              'Queue for Playlist, containing songnames
        Dim queueCount As Integer = 0                   'Count for queueArray


'DoubleClick track playlist to add selected track to Queue
Private Sub lvTrackList_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object,
                          ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lvTrackList.DoubleClick

    intCurrentSong = lvTrackList.SelectedIndices(0)
    lvQueueList.Items.Add(lvTrackList.Items(lvTrackList.SelectedIndices(0)).Clone())

    'determine applicable mp3 file
    currentSong = lvQueueList.Items(0).Text
    If currentSong = "Billy Lyons and Stackolee" Then
        newSong = songsArray(0)
    ElseIf currentSong = "Gus Cannon" Then
        newSong = songsArray(1)
    ElseIf currentSong = "Kansas Joe McCoy" Then
        newSong = songsArray(2)
    ElseIf currentSong = "Louis Armstrong" Then
        newSong = songsArray(3)
    End If

    'add file to queueArray for appending to WindowsMediaPlayer playlist
    ReDim queueArray(queueCount)
    queueArray(queueCount) = newSong

    queueCount += 1

End Sub
```

Comment: Please show the definitions for at least `songsArray`, `queueArray` and `queueCount`.

Comment: Clearly you are going to have to get rid of that awful code that checks "currentSong".  That will just add Nothing.  The item you added is not lvQueueList.Items(0), it got added at the end.

Comment: edited ... I've added the info for songsArray and such, but as you can see, the queueArray and queueCount are nothing special.

Answer (score 0):

First, unless there is a specific reason to write the code using arrays, I would suggest creating an object that will hold the song title and mp3 path and then load those items into list.

To hopefully answer your question, the line:

```
currentSong = lvQueueList.Items(0).Text
```

Is always grabbing the first item in the second list view, so it will always load the mp3 for that song into the currentSong variable.

To remove the queueArray items from showing nothing, you cannot simply ReDim the array. You need to ReDim Preserve the array and then add to end of the array. This way you can keep the current items in the array and just add to the end.

```
ReDim Preserve queueArray(UBound(queueArray) + 1)
queueArray(queueCount) = newSong
queueCount += 1
```

[MSDN Redim with Preserve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)